# Managing state in asp.net mvc C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

On loading the application, table with list of items is displayed.

On clicking the save button, i want to write the list of items to excel.

When i click the save button, in the new request send to the controller,the list is empty.I do not prefer to write the list of table items to database.

Could anyone advice me on how to do handle this?

```
public IActionResult SaveReport(SalesParentViewModel salesParentViewModel)
    {
        if(salesParentViewModel.SalesDataModelItems != null)
        {
            var buffer = new StringBuilder();
            buffer.AppendLine("#UserCode,SalesmanName,Date,ItemCode,ItemDescription,BrandCode,BrandName,ClientCode,Client,ClientBranchCode,Description, BranchSubChannel,TransactionAmount,Quantity");
            salesParentViewModel.SalesDataModelItems.ToList().ForEach(item => buffer.AppendLine
            (String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13}", item.UserCode, item.SALESMANNAME, item.DATE, item.ItemCode, item.ITEMDESCRIPTION, item.BRANDCODE, item.BRANDNAME, item.ClientCode, item.Client, item.ClientBranchCode, item.Description, item.BRANCHSUBCHANNEL, item.TrxAmount, item.QTY
            )));
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\\temp\\file.csv", buffer.ToString());
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View is as below:

```
@model MyStoreReports.ViewModels.SalesParentViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sales Report";
}

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h1>Sales Report</h1>

        </div> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"  runat="server" Text="Click Me!">
            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>Filter
        </asp:Button>


        @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveReport", "App", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems);
            <asp:Button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveReport","App")'" runat="server" Text="Click Me!">
                <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save
            </asp:Button>
        }

        @*<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save
        </a>*@
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
            <i class="fa fa-print"></i>Print
        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <form method="post">
            <asp:Panel id="pnlFilter" runat="server" GroupingText="This is a sample group text" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <div class="col-sm-10" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label asp-for="SalesViewModelInstance.StartDate">StartDate</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input asp-for="SalesViewModelInstance.StartDate" type="date" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="SalesViewModelInstance.StartDate" class="text-muted"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label asp-for="SalesViewModelInstance.EndDate">EndDate</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input asp-for="SalesViewModelInstance.EndDate" type="date" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="SalesViewModelInstance.EndDate" class="text-muted"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                                        <a asp-controller="App" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                     </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        </form>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                 @if (Model.SalesDataModelItems != null)
                 {
                      <div class="container" style="background-color:lavender;" >
                           <div class="row">
                                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                     <div class="panel-heading">
                                          <h2>Report</h2>
                                     </div>
                                    <div class="VScrollTable">
                                        <table id="myTable" class="table table-fixed table-responsive" align="left" cellspacing="0">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>UserCode</th>
                                                    <th>SalesmanName</th>
                                                    <th>Date</th>
                                                    <th>ItemCode</th>
                                                    <th>ItemDescription</th>
                                                    <th>BrandCode</th>
                                                    <th>BrandName</th>
                                                    <th>ClientCode</th>
                                                    <th>Client</th>
                                                    <th>ClientBranchCode</th>
                                                    <th>Description</th>
                                                    <th>BranchSubChannel</th>
                                                    <th>TransactionAmount</th>
                                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            @foreach (var item in Model.SalesDataModelItems)
                                            {
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>

                                                        <td>@item.UserCode</td>
                                                        <td>@item.SALESMANNAME</td>
                                                        <td>@item.DATE</td>
                                                        <td>@item.ItemCode</td>
                                                        <td>@item.ITEMDESCRIPTION</td>
                                                        <td>@item.BRANDCODE</td>
                                                        <td>@item.BRANDNAME</td>
                                                        <td>@item.ClientCode</td>
                                                        <td>@item.Client</td>
                                                        <td>@item.ClientBranchCode</td>
                                                        <td>@item.Description</td>
                                                        <td>@item.BRANCHSUBCHANNEL</td>
                                                        <td>@item.TrxAmount</td>
                                                        <td>@item.QTY</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            }
                                        </table>
                                    </div>

                               </div>

                         </div>
                  </div>
               }

      </div>         
</div>
```

Comment: Where list it empty? In the action method parameter salesParentViewModel?

Comment: List is SalesDataModelItems

Comment: Question is where you get it empty, in your action parameter you get it empty? If yes then you should show the code which you used to post view model to controller.

Comment: Yes, in the action parameter it is empty.

Comment: { <asp:Button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveReport","App")'" runat="server" Text="Click Me!">
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save
        </asp:Button> }

Comment: That's the save button

Comment: I suggest you should update your question with code, rather then adding code in comments! That will improve chance of getting answer. You should also show how you bind values in view to view model.

Comment: I think you need to show view code as well - since it will show how `SalesDataModelItems` bound to. Also, mixing web forms server control with MVC controller logic is not so good idea - use plain `<input type="button" ... />` instead.

Comment: Addendum: If `Model.SalesDataModelItems` populated dynamically depending on user input, try `for` loop with `@item[i].[[PropertyName]]` instead using `foreach`, or create `EditorTemplate` for them.

Comment: Thanks Tetsuya Yamamoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no change is done in the model, why would you want to pass the entire model from the view to the controller?
Just pass an identifier of some sort like id, and get the data again in the controller and save it in Excel.

If you must pass the model back to the controller it can be done, but the data needs to be hidden inputs or editable input controls (text box, check box)

Your view should look similar to the following :

```
@model MyStoreReports.ViewModels.SalesParentViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sales Report";
}

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h1>Sales Report</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveReport", "App", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <input id="brnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" value="Save" />

            <div class="form-group">
                @if (Model.SalesDataModelItems != null)
                {
                    <div class="container" style="background-color:lavender;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h2>Report</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="VScrollTable">
                                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-fixed table-responsive" align="left" cellspacing="0">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>UserCode</th>
                                                <th>SalesmanName</th>
                                                <th>Date</th>
                                                <th>ItemCode</th>
                                                <th>ItemDescription</th>
                                                <th>BrandCode</th>
                                                <th>BrandName</th>
                                                <th>ClientCode</th>
                                                <th>Client</th>
                                                <th>ClientBranchCode</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th>BranchSubChannel</th>
                                                <th>TransactionAmount</th>
                                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SalesDataModelItems.Count; i++)

                                        {
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].UserCode</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].SalesManName</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].SaleDate</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].ItemCode</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].ItemDescription</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].BrandCode</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].BrandName</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].ClientCode</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].ClientName</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].ClientBranchCode</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].Description</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].BranchSubChannel</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].TrxAmount</td>
                                                    <td>@Model.SalesDataModelItems[i].Quantity</td>

                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].UserCode) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].SalesManName) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].SaleDate) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].ItemCode) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].ItemDescription) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].BrandCode) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].BrandName) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].ClientCode) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].ClientName) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].ClientBranchCode) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].Description) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].BranchSubChannel) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].TrxAmount) </td>
                                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SalesDataModelItems[i].Quantity) </td>

                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        }
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

And like Tetsuya Yamamoto pointed out, avoid mixing asp web forms controls in asp.net MVC application

**EDIT (After Maria comments) :**

You can add an ajax call to save the data in excel on button press :

Controller Savereport method :

```
public ActionResult SaveReport()
        {
            try
            {
           // Get data from DB and save it in excel

            return Json("Success save report");
             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json("Save report failure!" + ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

View :

```
@model MVCWebApplication.Controllers.SalesParentViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sales Report";
}

@section scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h1>Sales Report</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div>

            <input id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-url="@Url.Action("SaveReport","App")" value="Save" />
            <div class="form-group">
                @if (Model.SalesDataModelItems != null)
                {
                    <div class="container" style="background-color:lavender;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h2>Report</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="VScrollTable">
                                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-fixed table-responsive" align="left" cellspacing="0">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>UserCode</th>
                                                <th>SalesmanName</th>
                                                <th>Date</th>
                                                <th>ItemCode</th>
                                                <th>ItemDescription</th>
                                                <th>BrandCode</th>
                                                <th>BrandName</th>
                                                <th>ClientCode</th>
                                                <th>Client</th>
                                                <th>ClientBranchCode</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th>BranchSubChannel</th>
                                                <th>TransactionAmount</th>
                                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model.SalesDataModelItems)
                                        {
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>@item.UserCode</td>
                                                    <td>@item.SalesManName</td>
                                                    <td>@item.SaleDate</td>
                                                    <td>@item.ItemCode</td>
                                                    <td>@item.ItemDescription</td>
                                                    <td>@item.BrandCode</td>
                                                    <td>@item.BrandName</td>
                                                    <td>@item.ClientCode</td>
                                                    <td>@item.ClientName</td>
                                                    <td>@item.ClientBranchCode</td>
                                                    <td>@item.Description</td>
                                                    <td>@item.BranchSubChannel</td>
                                                    <td>@item.TrxAmount</td>
                                                    <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                                    }

                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

            </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('url'),
                type: 'post',
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you mention how to pass the id (pointing to model) from the view to controller? The model contains huge data values, as you mentioned i wanted to pass id

Comment: In your scenario your SaveReport method should be called just before loading the view. and it should have a different signature.Just get the data from the db as you do, save it the excel and load the view. These methods should be in your controller.

Comment: I need to display the data on the view page, only whenthe user clicks save button it has to be saved to the excel

Comment: Thanks. But as i have mentioned in the question, i do not want to get the data from the database, as the retrieved data is so huge, it is a time consuming operation

Comment: well HTTP is a stateless protocol by nature, so when posting to the server you need to get the data again from db. You can add an indication to the client that a time consuming operation is running in the background.